Why the MouseLeave event get trigger even if the mouse cursor is still inside the pictureBox control?
this is the part in the code:
pictureBox.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
{
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
    pictureBox.Controls.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = tooltipText,
        ForeColor = Color.White,
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 0, 0, 0),
        AutoSize = false,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    });
};

pictureBox.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
{
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    pictureBox.Controls.Clear();
};

the problem is that when i move the mouse cursor inside the pictureBox area then when i move the mouse around inside the pictureBox area not leaving only inside then sometimes it's triggering the MouseLeave event code.
the full method code:
private void ArrangeImagesInCollage(string[] filePaths)
{
    int imageCount = filePaths.Length;
    int margin = 5;

    int columns = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(imageCount));
    int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)imageCount / columns);

    int panelWidth = panelCollage.Width - (columns + 1) * margin;
    int panelHeight = panelCollage.Height - (rows + 1) * margin;
    int imageWidth = panelWidth / columns;
    int imageHeight = panelHeight / rows;

    panelCollage.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        string filePath = filePaths[i];
        Image img = Image.FromFile(filePath);

        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox
        {
            Image = img,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Size = new Size(imageWidth, imageHeight),
            Padding = new Padding(3)
        };

        int row = i / columns;
        int col = i % columns;
        int x = col * (imageWidth + margin) + margin;
        int y = row * (imageHeight + margin) + margin;

        pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

        ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        string tooltipText = $"Name: {fileInfo.Name}\nSize: {fileInfo.Length / 1024} KB\nDimensions: {img.Width}x{img.Height}";
        toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, tooltipText);

        pictureBox.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
        {
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
            pictureBox.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = tooltipText,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                BackColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 0, 0, 0),
                AutoSize = false,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            });
        };

        pictureBox.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
        {
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox.Controls.Clear();
        };

        panelCollage.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }
} 


Is it happening in particular areas of the picturebox, or can it happen anywhere?

You have added a child Control to the PictureBox. When the Mouse pointer enters it, you get a MouseLeave event, of course, since the pointer is now inside the child Control's surface -- Instead of using a Label, just paint that text (and a background color, if needed)

It's because you've added a control (Label) to the pictureBox. If you hoover over this control, the pictureBox 'thinks' you leave the control because the label is another component.

this is working perfect.  instead creating and adding a label child control to the picturebox i draw it on the picturebox using the paint event.  i added a local isIn bool variable.
the result when entering with the mouse to the pictureBox:

and when leaving , back to the original:

private void ArrangeImagesInCollage(string[] filePaths)
{
    int imageCount = filePaths.Length;
    int margin = 5;

    int columns = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(imageCount));
    int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)imageCount / columns);

    int panelWidth = panelCollage.Width - (columns + 1) * margin;
    int panelHeight = panelCollage.Height - (rows + 1) * margin;
    int imageWidth = panelWidth / columns;
    int imageHeight = panelHeight / rows;

    panelCollage.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        string filePath = filePaths[i];
        Image img = Image.FromFile(filePath);

        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox
        {
            Image = img,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Size = new Size(imageWidth, imageHeight),
            Padding = new Padding(3)
        };

        int row = i / columns;
        int col = i % columns;
        int x = col * (imageWidth + margin) + margin;
        int y = row * (imageHeight + margin) + margin;

        pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

        ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        string tooltipText = $"Name: {fileInfo.Name}\nSize: {fileInfo.Length / 1024} KB\nDimensions: {img.Width}x{img.Height}";

        bool isIn = false;

        pictureBox.Paint += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (isIn)
            {
                // Define a semi-transparent overlay color
                Color overlayColor = Color.FromArgb(200, 0, 0, 0);

                // Draw the overlay rectangle
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(overlayColor), 0, 0, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);

                // Define the font for the text
                Font font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);

                // Measure the size of the text
                SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tooltipText, font);

                // Calculate the centered position for the text
                float xx = (pictureBox.Width - textSize.Width) / 2;
                float yy = (pictureBox.Height - textSize.Height) / 2;

                // Draw the text centered within the PictureBox
                e.Graphics.DrawString(tooltipText, font, Brushes.White, new PointF(xx, yy));
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the background color back to transparent when not hovering
                pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }
        };

        pictureBox.MouseEnter += (s, e) =>
        {
            isIn = true;
            pictureBox.Invalidate();
        };

        pictureBox.MouseLeave += (s, e) =>
        {
            isIn = false;
            pictureBox.Invalidate();
        };

        panelCollage.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }
}

